# Как можно закрепить див к другому диву

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть код:

```html
<div class="bubble" id="bubble"></div>
<div class="ball" id="ball"></div>
```

Я делаю игру.
Нужно "прикрепить" див "bubble"  к "ball".

Зачем это нужно?
В игре есть движение игрока и нужно привязать этот объект к нему чтобы при его движении он всегда был с ним.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если у вас игра на html элементах, то просто добавьте элемент `#ball` внутрь элемента `#bubble`.

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0;
}

#bubble {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  position: relative;
  animation: way 10s linear infinite;
}

#ball {
  display: block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: -15px;
}

@keyframes way {
   0% {left: 0vw;  top: 15px;}
  10% {left: 10vw; top: 50vh;}
  20% {left: 30vw; top: 60vh;}
  30% {left: 50vw; top: 20vh;}
  40% {left: 20vw; top: 60vh;}
  50% {left: 50vw; top: 70vh;}
  60% {left: 60vw; top: 80vh;}
  70% {left: 80vw; top: 40vh;}
  80% {left: 40vw; top: 10vh;}
  90% {left: 20vw; top: 20vh;}
 100% {left: 0vw;  top: 15px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="bubble">
  <div id="ball"></div>
</div>
```